# Validate user input as an integer and NOT as a decimal or anything else c

Tags: c++, stream, controls

So I've looked this up and most of the solutions I've seen only make sure that it's a number being entered, and then if the user enters a decimal value, it just drops the fractional value, and keeps the whole number.

Basically I want it to

```
//ask for integer value
//check for valid integer value
//if anything but an integer value throw an error and loop back to start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be better solutions, but to be 100% sure the user entered an integer value: save whole input into a std::string. Now go through ever character an make sure it is a digit (0...9). This way you will detect periods, commas and everything what is no digit.

Comment: You also need to ensure that the input doesn't overflow (e.g. `11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`)

Answer (score 0):

May be something like this :

```
    #include<limits>

    float x;
    int num;

    while(true){

    if (!(cin >> x)) {
        cout << "Not a Real Number" << endl;
        // do something
    }
    else {
        num = x;
    }

     std::cin.clear();
     std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
  }
```